# pgAdmin4: remote access to PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I can access the remote PostgreSQL server in the lab from both the terminal and using pgAdmin4 when connected to same private network.

From Terminal:

```
PC:~$ psql -h 193.13x.xx.xx -U myusername -W dbname
#then password after prompt
```

Using pgAmin4:

```
Host name/address: 193.13x.xx.xx
Port: 5432
Maintainance database: dbname
Username: myusername
Password: *******
```

However, when I switched to another network `eduroam`, I can only connect to the remote server via the terminal, not from pgAdmin4. So it is not very easy to work away from the lab.

Is there a workaround to enable connecting via pgAdmin4?

Comment: Do you get an error Message?

Comment: Yes, `'could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "193.13x.xx.xx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?'`

Comment: Did you check for a Firewall ( on your local machine) blocking outgoing connections for one application but not the other?

Comment: Yes, checked with localhost firewall settings.

Answer (score 2):

> *I can only connect to the remote server via the terminal, not from
>   pgAdmin4. So it is not very easy to work away from the lab.
>   Is there a workaround to enable connecting via pgAdmin4?*

Yes. The generic answer to that is: use an [SSH tunnel](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssh-tunnels.html). It's very usual when you cannot access directly a database from outside a certain network, which appears to be your case based on the error message in the comments.

If you need specific advice for pgAdmin4, consider searching for "pgadmin4 ssh tunnel", there are many tutorials available online.

Comment: If that is the solution, then why can OP connect with `psql`? Both are using `libpq`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: my interpretation of _I can only connect to the remote server via the terminal_ is the OP does ssh and psql in the local session, not a remote psql.